# How to get Server Time using Ajax request?

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

In my Rails app (Examination System), I need to make a validation with Server Time.

On a button **click** function, fetch server time and validate the same. Now I am fetching it using Time.now method, but it fails to fetch server time dynamically. Means, it keeps on showing the server time that is fetched during the page load.

How can I do the above using an Ajax request? Now my app is in development mode. So the Client and Server machine are the same. So, please get me some solution for the same.

Answer (score 0):

call the ajax function which gets server time and display,every second.
So that the server time is refreshed every second..You need to cal the function everysecond.

ex

```
 window.setInterval(function(){
      /// call your function here
    //function to get server time and display.
function ShowData();
    }, 1000)
//
suppose div to display time..

<div id="datePanel"></div>

//function to get server tym from servertime.php
<script language="JavaScript">  
ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();

function ShowData()
{  
  ajax.open( "GET", "servertime.php", true );  
  ajax.onreadystatechange = function() 
  {
    if ( ajax.readyState == 4 ) 
    {      
      document.getElementById("DataPanel").innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
    }
  }    
  ajax.send(null);
}  
</script>
```